# Is it on-topic to ask about techniques for empirically evaluating a language's success at achieving a specific, commonly-sought design goal?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Such goals may include (but are not limited to): readability, usability, performance, maintainability, etc.

Are there cases when such questions should be considered off-topic? (aside from the reasons laid out in /help/dont-ask) If so, what and *why*?

Comment: Presumably related: [Is the mental overhead / cognitive load of learning and remembering how a language's features work measurable? If so, how?](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/q/923/133) is currently closed as off-topic, which I think is untenable. It's a core part of the field and practice and widely-studied. There could be an argument for being too broad, but to identify the empirical study of language features as not about language design is extreme.